# Stream reduce incorrectly working with long type

Tags: java, java-stream

I want convert string line to long digit.
I do this:

```
 String line = "eRNLpuGgnON";
 char[] chars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890-_".toCharArray();
 Map<Character, Integer> charToInt =
            IntStream.rangeClosed(0, chars.length - 1)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors
                            .toMap(i -> (chars[i]), i -> i));

long l =  line.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            .map(charToInt::get)
            .reduce((int) 0L, ((a, b) -> a * chars.length + b));
System.out.println(l);
```

I take the corresponding indexes in the map by the symbol and perform the shortest operation of multiplication and addition.

Example. I have a line eRNLpuGgnON. These symbols have such values in the `Map`:

```
e=2
R=29
N=50
....
```

The algorithm is very simple:

```
0*64+2 = 2
2*64 + 29 = 157
157*64 + 50 = 10098
........
```

In the end, I need to get this value:

```
2842528454463293618
```

But I get this value:

```
-1472624462
```

And, if the value of the `line` is short enough, everything works fine. I can not understand why there is not work properly with values of the Long.

Comment: Your reduction is not [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity).

Comment: @shmosel, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using integers in the reduce operation, so you reach the Integer.MAX_VALUE giving you wrong results. Using long in your charToInt map is the way to go:

```
Map<Character, Long> charValues = IntStream.range(0, chars.length)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> chars[i], Long::valueOf));

long l =  line.chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .map(charValues::get)
        .reduce(0L, (a, b) -> a * chars.length + b);

System.out.println(l);
// prints "2842528454463293618"
```